# How to assign more than one value to UInt32

Tags: xcode

I am trying to set the bird group as two numbers so that when I assign a variable I can use multiple "else if" statements with that one group later on 
Code:

Xcode doesn't let me do this I'm in Swift

Let birdgroup: UInt32 = 2, 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array`, `Set`, or a tuple to store multiple values in a single variable. If order matters, go with `Array` or tuple, but if the order doesn't matter, you can use `Set`. `Array` and `Set` both allow you to vary the number of values stored in your variable, while a tuple variable must always be the same length. Also, you can loop over the items in an array or set, but not over a tuple.

`Array` is the most often used of the three, so if you aren't sure which to use, it's a good first choice.

In summary, this table shows the possibilities and their properties:

```
           Loopable  Unloopable
Ordered    Array     Tuple
Unordered  Set       (none)
```

Finally, all the items in an array or set must be of the same type (or derived from the same type, if the array or set is defined with the base class). This is called homogeneous. A tuple can contain different types, also known as heterogeneous.

```
           Homogeneous  Heterogeneous
Ordered    Array        Tuple
Unordered  Set          (none)
```

[Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) in the Swift documentation describes how to use `Array` and `Set`.

## Array

Create an array with

```
var birdgroup: [UInt32] = [2, 3]
```

`birdgroup[0]` is equal to 2, and `birdgroup[1]` is equal to 3. You can also access the items by looping:

```
for bird in birdgroup {
    println("\(bird)")
}
```

## Set

You can declare a set with

```
var birdgroup: Set<UInt32> = [2, 3]
```

Because sets have no order (imagine every item is tossed together in a bag), you can't request the "first" or "second" item. Instead, loop over each item of the set:

```
for bird in birdgroup {
    println("\(bird)")
}
```

## Tuple

```
let birdgroup: (UInt32, UInt32) = (2, 3)
```

Tuples also retain the order of their items. `birdgroup.0` is equal to 2, and `birdgroup.1` to 3. You can also give each item of the tuple a name if you prefer that to a number:

```
let birdgroup: (UInt32, UInt32) = (foo: 2, bar: 3)
```

`birdgroup.foo` is 2, and `birdgroup.bar` is 3.

Additionally, the values in a tuple do not all need to be the same type. You can combine different types, such as

```
let heterogeneousTuple: (UInt32, String) = (2, "three")
```

Comment: Dang! Thanks this is Perfect!